# How to automatically login user once he/she verifies using email verification link sent through email

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js

How to automatically login user once he/she verifies using email verification link sent through email. Current Verification Handler is:

```js
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var User = require("../models/user");
var Token = require("../models/token");

router.get("/:id", function(req, res){
  Token.findOne({token: req. params.id}, function(err, response){
    if(response){
      User.update({_id: response._userId},{ isVerified : true}, function(err, user){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      req.body.username = user.username;
      });
      res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/profile/"+ req.body.username);
    }
  })
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Use token based url to authenticate and login after verifying the token

Comment: is there way to automatically login, when token is verified? @SureshPrajapati

Comment: You can repeat what you are doing after successful login, like setting cookies in session and redirecting him on dashboard